# ListGrid.updateData() for multiple records

Tags: smartclient

**Is there an smartClient solution to update multiple?**

`saveAllEdits` didn't send any update request to the server, `updateData` works on a single Record object, if I try to send an array it ends up at the server as

```
0:{
    name:"example",
    permission:"high"
},
1:{
    name:"test",
    permission:"low"
},
2:{
    name:"inquery",
    permisson:"low"
}
```

I need a solution that will send the request as

```
records:[
    {
        name:"example",
        permission:"high"
    },
    {
        name:"test",
        permission:"low"
    },
    {
        name:"inquery",
        permisson:"low"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **queueing**:

```
RPCManager.startQueue();
grid.updateData(record1);
grid.updateData(record2);
RPCManager.sendQueue();
```

Comment: thanks @claudiobosticco, I can see that I'm going to be contributing to your SO score significantly

Comment: actually it seems ***queueing*** only works for smart GWT. We're running against c#

Comment: Are you using SmartClient LGPL ?
I'm not sure but I think that RestDataSource supports queueing...otherwise take a look at this blog post:
https://smartclientexperience.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/saving-all-listgrid-changes-at-once/